# How can set Element Id for a image which is accessed using ClientBundle in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, clientbundle

In GWT, I need to set element id for a image which will be accessed using ClientBundle.

For eg. `@Source("logo.png")`

```
     ImageResource logo();
```

Instead of Image I'm calling this logo(). But I want to set element Id for logo.png.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
Resources resources = GWT.create(Resources.class);
Image img = new Image(resources.logo());
img.getElement().setID("ID");
```

Is it what you want ?